# Can't get the followers for a specfic User on Twitter

Tags: r, list, twitter, vector

I want to get the follower names for 'Pogo' on twitter using the twitteR package.

Here is my code:

```
start<-getUser("Pogo")
friends.object<-lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs())

There are 46 warnings (use warnings() to see them
```

So I did that command and this came up:

```
1: In TwInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "lookup", sep="/"), ...: 
Rate limit encountered & retry limit reached - returning partial results
(It says the same thing 46 times)
```

Then when I just run:

```
friends.object
```

it returns a list of 18,000 FollowerIDs and their username:

```
$'423288139
[1]"mrskamakazi"
```

My goal is to get the actual names of the followers? Any ideas would be really helpful. Thanks

Pogo has over 20,000 followers which might be a reason but this even happens when I do this with a user that only has 3,000.

My ultimate goal is to get the names of the followers and get the gender of each of the followers' first names.

Comment: Check out https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting, https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits and https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

Comment: So do you think the problem is just that I used it too many times? I tried changing my access key with the same application and the same thing still happened

Comment: Yea I'd say if the error says "Rate limit encountered" then you exceeded the rate limit for the api method. So you gotta wait 15 minutes or so, then you can continue - again within the given limits.

Comment: So I tried that and I still wasn't able to get the names, only the follower name like @dank123...what I am trying to get the actual name such as Dan Kiewl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given for example:

```
start<-getUser("lukeAnker")
friends.object<-lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs())

length(friends.object)
# [1] 863

class(friends.object[[1]])
# [1] "user"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "twitteR"

# View help on the "user" class
?user
```

You could retrieve the Twitter handle of a follower by using `friends.object[[1]]$getScreenName()`.  Now, to get the names of the followers:

```
# Get one specific user name: 
friends.object[[455]]$getName()
# [1] "Email Marketing Buch"

# Get a vector containing all user names:
sapply(friends.object, function(x) x$getName())
```